# react-router hashHistory Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property location of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As you can see below, I want to define a ROUTER in REACT but it doesn't work well, while their dependencies are added correctly?

Is there anybody to help me?

[image: Error screen shot]

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`."

bundle.js:115641 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at new Router
```

Comment: What version of `react-router`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import hashHistory directly from folder
`import hashHistory from 'react-router/lib/hashHistory';`
Or 
`import { hashHistory } from 'react-router/lib/hashHistory';`, see how it's exported.